# PHP - Not working on Mac, showing directory listing instead of running index.php

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

After installing PHP on my Mac with `brew install php` and followed these given instructions on Terminal,

> To enable PHP in Apache add the following to httpd.conf and restart Apache:

```
LoadModule php_module /opt/homebrew/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

> Finally, check DirectoryIndex includes index.php

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

and `brew services restart httpd` and `brew services start php` and add `index.php` to my `www` directory and `chmod 755` it and `http://localhost`, at the end I got `Index of /` directory listing instead of `index.php` PHP code execution result.

Run `apachectl -M` also showed `php_module (shared)` on the list.

Did I miss something?

Comment: I am not familiar with the Mac environment, but `brew services start php` does not sound right when you are using php as a module within the http server ...

Comment: What does your http server's error log file contain if you restart the http server?

Comment: @arkascha believe me it'll sounds right if you're familiar with it. what error?

Comment: Your first code block contains a stray "`". I assume that is a c&p flaw, not part of the actual configuration?

Comment: And what is that pattern meant to express? `\. php$` What is the blank doing in there?

Comment: @arkascha just some typos. edited

Comment: if you go to http://localhost/index.php does PHP operate fine? I think you just need to instruct Apache to use index.php instead of serving directory listing when the path is accessed

Comment: @PatrickMoore it shows php code as a text